# Google gauge giving error when sending a new value

Tags: javascript, google-gauges

I am getting a reference error that `data1` is not defined, my form is visible and I can see 3 circles that I have made. But when I want to update it I am getting reference error.

Here is my code for drawing which is working:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['A', 0],
        ]);
        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['B', 0]
        ]);
        var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Label', 'Value'],
          ['C', 0]
        ]);

        var options1 = {
          width: 150, height: 170,
          min:0, max:200,
          minorTicks: 5
        };
        var options2 = {
          width: 150, height: 170,
          min:0, max:7000,
          minorTicks: 5
        };
        var options3 = {
          width: 150, height: 170,
          min:0, max:30,
          minorTicks: 5
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('visualization1'));
        var chart2 = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('visualization2'));
        var chart3 = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('visualization3'));
        chart.draw(data1, options1);
        chart2.draw(data2, options2);
        chart3.draw(data3, options3);
      }
```

And this is the function that I am using for adding a new value to `data1`

```
function changeSpeed(dir) {
      console.log(dir);
     data1.setValue(0, 0, dir);
    chart.draw(data1, options1);
    }
```

Probably my functions is not set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables `options1`, `options2` and `options3`, also `data1`, `data2` and `data3` are defined in local scope. You need to change you function like this:

```
function changeSpeed(dir, options, data) {
   data.setValue(0, 0, dir);
   chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

And use it:

```
changeSpeed(dir, options1, data1);
```

Or, you can define variables in global scope.

Comment: global scope variables worked for me :) thank you good answer